# Failed to load Widgetset (path) error while executing fresh custom widget in vaadin 6

Tags: widget, vaadin

I created a simple Vaadin 6 application. By right clicking that project in eclipse i created simple custom widget and try to run. Error occurs which says

`Failed to load the widgetset:/testcomapp/VAADIN/Widgetsets
com.example.testcompapp.TestcompappWidgetset.nocache.js?1409642685672`

this error is in the form of alert box on browser. No error in Eclipse's Console.

I don't know what is wrong with it. I haven.t write a single line by myself
`Note: I am using VAADIN 6`

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for my question. Hope it will help anybody of u. This error will be removed by compiling the widget by pressing ctrl+6. Very easy solution